# Creating a multilingual Excel template spreadsheet

Tags: excel, templates, localization, internationalization

I have created an Excel template to collect data from multiple sources in a standard format. Pretty soon, I will be sending this template to people from different countries. I would like them to be able to select the language of the template directly from within the Excel workbook. This would enable them to have the headers translated in their own languages. I want to support 4 major languages and I can provide the translations of my headers in these languages.

Is there a good solution to do this? Could my Excel workbook embed a set of `*.properties` files containing the translations? Or should I use nasty formulas to retrieve the headers from a hidden sheet? Should I use VBA and how?

Of course, another solution would be for me to create 4 different files. But I feel this will become a nightmare when I want to support more languages or make changes to my template.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a `nasty formula` because your recipients might not appreciate the security risks of VBA, amongst other considerations. If you have a range with Language names (or other references) in a column (say a named range of `HLcol1`) and the appropriate headers in a matrix alongside `HLcol1` (with the entire array named say `HeaderLanguage`then:

```
=INDEX(HeaderLanguage,MATCH($A$6,HLcol1,0),COLUMN())
```

in B6 and copied across might suit, where the chosen Language name (or other reference) is in A6.

`6` because rows 1-5 seem as good a place as anywhere to place the lookup array - these rows could be hidden.